# Loading a text files with unequal columns

Tags: python-3.x, file, numpy, text

I have a text file with unstructured data. The file contains 150k lines like

```
M  Jackson                              1                                             $
F  Fiza                                 1                                             $
M  Aaro                                          41                                   $
M  Micheal                      226 4   2   211                               6       $
```

the first column is the gender information, second is the name, the third column can have 1 or more numbers separated by space representing the probable countries the person might belong to. (Each country have one code). Symbol $ is end of line.

I have to take the data in to numpy array. When I scan the lines of the text to array, it shows error as it has unequal columns.

```
data = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype= 'str', delimiter = ' ')
```

How to scan data in that case in to arrays? The spaces are also not constant but the numbers are separated by space. 
In case of my data, first line have 3 values, 4 th line have 6 columns. Later I make the empty columns to zero to make it the equal number of columns and do the feature extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy loaders don't handle missing data very well.  But in `genfromtxt` you can specify field widths.

```
In [103]: txt = """one 2 3
     ...: two   4 5
     ...: """.splitlines()


In [105]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=[3,2,2,2])
Out[105]: 
array([[nan,  2.,  3., nan],
       [nan, nan,  4.,  5.]])

In [109]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=[3,2,2,2],dtype=str,encoding=None)
Out[109]: 
array([['one', ' 2', ' 3', ''],
       ['two', '  ', ' 4', ' 5']], dtype='<U3')
```